# How to display Stacked Bar graph/chart in android studio?

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I have to create a Stack-bar graph and my requirement is to graph should look like this.
[image]

I have checked many graph libraries but no one is providing this type of UI. 
is this possible to achieve?

Comment: only 3 fields right? and if any of the value is 0 it will vanish?  Hold on I can try but you need to take care of those rounded corners. Btw where did you get the screenshot from?

Comment: Not sure about how many values would be there, all are coming from server and it may decrease or increase. I get this from designing team, they provided this image as mock up.

Comment: i have posted a solution in that way you can add as many values you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found a way for that.

Step 1: Add 3 views with respective colors and a button like in below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:layout_width="75sp"
        android:layout_height="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/viewOverdue"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="75sp"
        android:layout_height="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2sp"
        android:background="#FFDD00"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/viewOverdue"
        android:id="@+id/viewActive"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="75sp"
        android:layout_height="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2sp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/viewActive"
        android:id="@+id/viewDone"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Overdue"
        android:id="@+id/editOverdue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewActive"
        android:layout_marginTop="100sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Active"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editOverdue"
        android:id="@+id/editActive"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Done"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editActive"
        android:id="@+id/editDone"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="submit"
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_below="@id/editDone"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it will Look:
[image: Before execution]
*Do note that views are set to invisible initially.*

Step 2: The coding part:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText typeActive, typeDone, typeOverdue;
    private Button btnSubmit;
    private View viewDone, viewOverDue, viewActive;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        typeActive = findViewById(R.id.editActive);
        typeDone = findViewById(R.id.editDone);
        typeOverdue = findViewById(R.id.editOverdue);

        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        viewDone = findViewById(R.id.viewDone);
        viewActive = findViewById(R.id.viewActive);
        viewOverDue = findViewById(R.id.viewOverdue);

        viewDone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewOverDue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewActive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //Type all the number of tasks and press the submit button
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String tasksActive = typeActive.getText().toString();
                final String tasksDone = typeDone.getText().toString();
                final String tasksOverdue = typeOverdue.getText().toString();

                int intTaskActive = Integer.parseInt(tasksActive);
                int intTaskDone = Integer.parseInt(tasksDone);
                int intTaskOverdue = Integer.parseInt(tasksOverdue);

                int totalTasks = intTaskActive + intTaskOverdue + intTaskDone;

                float percentageActive = (intTaskActive*100.0f)/totalTasks;
                float percentageDone   = (intTaskDone*100.0f)/totalTasks;
                float percentageOverdue = (intTaskOverdue*100.0f)/totalTasks;

                int intPercActive = (int)percentageActive;
                int intPercDone = (int)percentageDone;
                int intPercOverdue = (int)percentageOverdue;

                viewDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewOverDue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewActive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                viewDone.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(intPercDone*10, 50));
                viewActive.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(intPercActive*10, 50));
                viewOverDue.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(intPercOverdue*10, 50));

            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is the output after execution:
[image: after execution]

So how this works is you type the number of tasks in the edittext. It doesn't matter how you get the number of tasks but you need to convert it to percentage of total length of the stackBar or whatever you call it.
So finally you just assign each view the respective width as per the number.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will make required changes but thank you so much for showing the path.

Comment: Glad to know that code worked for you :-) Yeah you can modify its location and appearance as per need.

Comment: Actually my requirement is to create a totally dynamic view, there could be any number of entries and colors coming from backend. also the view would be the same.. and that was the main trouble for me.  Thank you so much once again.

Comment: @Devraj yeah this is dynamic. As I have typed the value manually. You can get those value anyhow from backend whether it be from a database or someone else from your team does it for you in backend. Enjoy